# Not getting pop ups in FOLIUM. Where am I wrong?

Tags: python, dataframe, folium

I am trying to add pop ups to the map. It is a map showing spacex launchsites. I see red marker points at the correct latitude, longitude but don't see the names of the launch sites as pop ups. Although I can see the names of the launch sites on clicking on them. Here is the code :

```
# Initial the map
site_map = folium.Map(location=nasa_coordinate, zoom_start=5)
# For each launch site, add a Circle object based on its coordinate (Lat, Long) values. In addition, add Launch site name as a popup label
for i,row in launch_sites_df.iterrows():
    coordinate = [row['Lat'],row['Long']]
    circle = folium.Circle(coordinate, radius=1000, color='#d35400', fill=True).add_child(folium.Popup(row['Launch Site']))
    folium.map.Marker(coordinate, icon=DivIcon(icon_size=(20,20),icon_anchor=(0,0), html='<div style="font-size: 12; color:#d35400;"><b>%s</b></div>' % row['Launch Site'], ))




    site_map.add_child(circle)
    site_map.add_child(marker)
site_map
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get your question since the result of clicking on a marker is a popup, and you seem to have it working. I tried your code to see if it works fine and found some changes you may try to have both marker and popup on the map.

Try to put popup as `popup` argument for instantiated `marker` object as `folium.Marker`, not as `.add_child()` chained method to the circle object:

```
for i, row in launch_sites_df.iterrows():

    coordinate = [row['Lat'], row['Long']]

    circle = folium.Circle(coordinate, 
                           radius=1000, 
                           color='#d35400', 
                           fill=True)

    marker = folium.Marker(coordinate,
                           popup=row['Launch Site'], # <- here
                           icon=folium.DivIcon(icon_size=(20, 20),
                                               icon_anchor=(0, 0),
                                               html='<div style="font-size: 12; color:#d35400;"><b>%s</b></div>' % row['Launch Site']))

    site_map.add_child(circle)
    site_map.add_child(marker)

site_map
```